# Jupyter notebook won't start, ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: jupyter-notebook, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to start jupyter notebook from my terminal, like i've done million of times before. Out of the sudden, a following Module Error is appearing and I can not find a solution anywhere.

`

```
(base) me518@PHS024636 ~ % conda activate mageckenv
(mageckenv) me518@PHS024636 ~ % jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me518/miniconda3/envs/mageckenv/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/me518/miniconda3/envs/mageckenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 59, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "/Users/me518/miniconda3/envs/mageckenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
  File "/Users/me518/miniconda3/envs/mageckenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tornado import iostream
  File "/Users/me518/miniconda3/envs/mageckenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tornado.netutil import ssl_wrap_socket, _client_ssl_defaults, _server_ssl_defaults
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado.netutil'
```

`

Any ideas with what's going on?

I tried activating all of my environments, nothing works.

Comment: Looks like module tornado.netutil is not available, even though you believe it is.  Check your assumptions.  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=miniconda3+tornado.netutil+module&t=osx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already tried to `pip install tornado` (since you also posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74711457/jupyter-notebook-wont-start)). Maybe do the following after `conda activate mageckenv`:

```bash
python -m pip install tornado
```

and see if this fix your problem.

Sometimes `pip` may use different environments and `python -m pip` makes sure it's using the specific `pip` you want.